# USB cable wiring

Tags: usb, wire

I have a USB cable from my old Samsung phone. There are four wires: red, white, green, and an unshielded wire.

These wires were in a foil-like cover which was surrounded by another unshielded wire. I will use this for the my USB webcam project, but which wire should I use for ground, the one that came inside with the foil-like cover or the wire that is surrounding the foil-like cover?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the black cable for GND (At the USB Device end), The foil shielding should be connected to GND on the host end and if this is being hard soldered (Not a connector) you can link the shielding to the Webcams GND as well.

[image]

Edit - Sorry re-read the question, yeah trim back the insulation until you find a black cable this will be GND, don't use the shielding as a GND cable.

Comment: Got it. Gonna try it now to my usb webcam.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cut it a bit more deep; usually the cables have four wires (red - Vcc, white - Data-, green - Data+, black - GND). These are surrounded by a foil acting as a shield, and for long wires sometimes I also found another uncovered wire acting as a shield as well